# Adding input from textarea/form to a list with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying to become a Front-End Developer and now react is on the menu. I need to create a react-app that has a grocery list and a shopping cart. I can add items to the grocery list and eventually I can click on them to transfer them to the shopping cart.

The whole react tree-like experience is quite new and overwhelming. But my question is, I need to add the data that I get from an input field to a UL/LI.

I have a GroceryList component, an InputField component, a List component, and a ListItem component.

The code I have now for the InputField works kind of but it displays the information directly on the screen and not on submit.

The code is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";


function InputField(props) {



    return (

        < div >
            <form>
                <input type="text" onChange={(event) => props.setGroceryName(event.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit" >Add Groceries</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    )
    
}


export default InputField
```

I defined the setGroceryName in the GroceryList component. Can someone help me with how I can change it so it makes a list in the List component? I'm really stuck and can't seem to find some good help. Or what do I need to do and where do I need to put it so it takes a ListItem and adds that to the List component.

Thanks in advance. If you guys need more info, let me know.

Comment: Please refer [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io).

Comment: I'm sorry... You 're right. Here is my entire code for now:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mccarthy-gctso

Comment: could you fix your sandbox please ? there are missing pieces. My initial reasoning is that you should keep an array of grocery items. do you have a separate state for keeping the whole list of grocery items ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Test extends Component {

    state = {
        grocery: '',
        groceryList: []
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ grocery: e.target.value })} />
                    <button type="submit" onClick={e => this.setState({ groceryList: [...this.state.groceryList, this.state.grocery], grocery: '' })}>Add Groceries</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You need to setState for every time the text is changing for a new grocery item and when clicked on the button, add it to the groceryList array, and set the initial text to an empty array.